# bundle install (gem not found) in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems, containers

I'm trying to create a docker image for Ruby on Rails application with a docker file.

the error I'm getting

```
Step 8/11 : RUN gem install bundler:2.3.24
 ---> Running in 19f290ad8c53
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 2.3.24), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Net::OpenTimeout: Net::OpenTimeout (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
The command '/bin/sh -c gem install bundler:2.3.24' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

The docker file is

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs ruby-full
RUN gem update --system
ENV GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH
# Install bundler and gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.3.24
RUN gem install bundler:2.3.24
RUN bundle install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Start your Rails application
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

NOTE: I'm getting this error on this server only but on the other server it worked fine!

please let me know if there is missing information

I tried to restart docker as follows
`sudo service docker restart`

but still the same

I tried also
`sudo docker prune system`

nothing happen

Comment: don't add images of the error -- add the error text to the question

Comment: Seems like you're getting a simple timeout. Is the container able to access the internet? Does the host machine have some security group or firewall-like rule that disables ingress from the internet?

Comment: The error shown in the image has to do with network issues. `Unable to download data... Net::OpenTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys after you told there a network error

I looked up the MTU in my interface vs docker

Docker was using higher MTU than the interface

I looked for a solution and I saw this reference

[MTU Overwrite](https://www.civo.com/learn/fixing-networking-for-docker)